# C# Reading Fixed Length File - Trimming Space in the values

Tags: c#, oledb, fixed

When I read fixed length file, The value is always without space.

Exmple: The folder c:\temp contains 2 files

**fs.txt**

```
ITMHMC12-163 -0000153430.30
ITMHMC12-164 -0000000745.18
```

**schema.ini**

```
[fs.txt]
ColNameHeader=False
Format=FixedLength
DateTimeFormat=yyyymmdd
Col1=RecordTypeSCFBody Text Width 3
Col2=InvoiceNumber Text Width 10
Col3=Amount Text Width 14
```

**C# code to read the file...**

```
string fileName = @"C:\temp\fs.txt";
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);

DataTable dataTable;

using (OleDbConnection conn =
    new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;" +
        "Data Source=" + dir + ";" +
        "Extended Properties=\"Text;\""))
{
conn.Open();

using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from " + fileName, conn))
{

    dataTable = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
}
conn.Close();
}

Console.Write(dataTable.Rows[0][1].ToString()); <-- this line **
```

-->this line gives me "HMC12-163", but I expect "HMC12-163 ". **Note the space!**

Appreciate your help.

Many thanks!
-Deb

Comment: "HMC12-163", but I expect "HMC12-163 " so that's good

Comment: For flexibility, use the `StreamReader` and populate your own `DataTable`. [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/55c6f58a-0781-4492-9060-657904ba7e74/) may be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There don't appear to be any documented settings to control this behavior.  You can explicity pad to the correct number of spaces in code or SQL if the trailing spaces are important:

```
const int maxInvoiceLength = 10;
string fileName = @"C:\temp\fs.txt";
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);

DataTable dataTable;

using (OleDbConnection conn =
    new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;" +
        "Data Source=" + dir + ";" +
        "Extended Properties=\"Text;\""))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string query = String.Format("SELECT RecordTypeSCFBody, LEFT(InvoiceNumber + SPACE({0}), {0}), Amount FROM {1}", maxInvoiceLength, fileName);
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
        {
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }
    }

    Console.Write(dataTable.Rows[0][1].ToString());
```

Comment: Hmm...Interesting solution. I just tested it, and it works! Thanks @Mike Payne.

I was assuming this can be achieved by using some configuration/parameters/options.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed length formatted text files, you should be specifying that in your extended properties:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\txtFilesFolder\;Extended Properties="text;HDR=No;FMT=Fixed";
```

"HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not data. "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite.
To specify each columns length use your [Schema.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353.aspx) file.

Hence your code becomes:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn =
    new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;" +
        "Data Source=" + dir + ";" +
        "Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=No;FMT=Fixed\""))
```

Comment: Kash, I am using StreamReader in actual code. I am able to read file without any issue, & do understand extended properties. I need the value should include the space and do not trim it. Note length of 'Col2' is '10', so I expect a string of '10' characters when I retrieve like `dataTable.Rows[0][1].ToString())`